the ffmpeg recording does not stop after the test case is successfully executed,
I am new to selenium, I want to add screen recording in my test cases, and I am using ffmpeg. The issue i am facing is the recording successfully starts, but it does not stop after the test case is successfully executed.
Below is how my code is strcutured:
package utilities;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ScreenRecording {

    private Process ffmpeg;
    private String outputFilePath;
    private boolean isRecording;

    public ScreenRecording(String outputFilePath) {
        this.isRecording = false;
        this.outputFilePath = outputFilePath;
    }

    public void startRecording() throws IOException {
        String command = String.format(
                "ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -probesize 100M -analyzeduration 10M -i desktop -vf \"crop=1920:1080:0:0\" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p %s",
                outputFilePath
        );
        System.out.println("Executing command: " + command); // Print command for debugging
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true); // Combine error and output streams
            ffmpeg = builder.start();
            isRecording = true;

            // Log output and errors
            new Thread(() -> {
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ffmpeg.getInputStream()))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // Print exception for debugging
            throw e; // Rethrow exception to propagate it to the caller
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        if (ffmpeg != null) {
            ffmpeg.destroy();
            System.out.println("Recording stopped.");
            isRecording = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isRecording() {
        return isRecording;
    }
}


public class AccountFeatures extends BaseTest {

    @Test(testName = "Register User")
    public void testRegisterUserScenario() throws InterruptedException {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        SignUpPage signUpPage = new SignUpPage(driver);
        homePage.clickOnLogin();
        Assert.assertEquals(loginPage.getSingupText(), "New User Signup!");
        loginPage.enterUserName(randomName);
        loginPage.enterUserEmail(randomEmail);
        loginPage.clickOnSignUpButton();
        signUpPage.clickOnTitle();
        signUpPage.enterPassword(randomPassword);
        signUpPage.selectDate(birthDay);
        signUpPage.selectMonth("December");
        signUpPage.selectYear();
        signUpPage.selectFromCountryDropDown("Canada");
    }
}

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import utilities.ScreenRecording;
import webdrivers.DriverManager;

import java.io.IOException;

public class BaseTest {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    private ScreenRecording recorder;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        // Initialize WebDriver (you can choose Chrome, Firefox, etc.)
        String outputFilePath = "D:\\Projects\\screen_recordings\\screen_recording.mp4";
        recorder = new ScreenRecording(outputFilePath);
        recorder.startRecording();
        driver = DriverManager.getDriver();
        driver.get(DataConfig.baseUrl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
        if (recorder != null && recorder.isRecording()) {
            recorder.stopRecording();
        }
    }
}

I tried different solutions but it does not work at all. Before that i was using @AfterTest annotations but it was giving stack overflow exception.
